# A harmonic function

Tags: cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

Consider the vertical strip of angle $\alpha=\frac{\pi}{2}$

In this case, the harmonic function which is $0$ on the left line and $1$ on the right line is given by $$f(a+ib)=\frac{a}{T}.$$
Now, when the angle $0<\alpha <\frac{\pi}{2}$ the strip becomes bent.

My question is: can we determine explicitly the harmonic function that is $0$ on left half lines and $1$ on the right ones. My attempt gave the following function
$$f(a+ib)=\frac{a}{T}- \frac{\cos(\alpha)}{\sin(\alpha)}\frac{|b|}{T},$$
but this is not a harmonic function. Thank you for any hint.

Comment: Usually in such problems one adds the condition that the function is bounded. Then it is unique.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it can be found explicitly, though not in elementary functions but in terms of a combination of elementary and hypergeometric functions.
The problem is (almost) equivalent to finding a conformal map
from your straight strip onto the broken strip. For this it is sufficient to find 
a conformal map from the upper half-plane onto the UPPER half of the broken strip (and then apply the Schwarz Symmetry principle). This map of the upper half-plane on the upper half
of the broken strip is given by the Christoffel-Schwarz formula
$$C\int_0^z\zeta^{\beta-1}(\zeta-T)^{-\beta} d\zeta,$$
where $\alpha=\pi\beta$. This integral can be explicitly expressed in terms of
hypergeometric function. I hope these hints are enough to make an explicit computation.

In a comment you ask about dependence on $T$. Dependence on $T$ is trivial:
If $F$ is the conformal mapping corresponding to $T=1$, normalized such that
$F(0)=0,F(1)=1,F(\infty_j)=\infty_j, j=1,2$ then $TF(z/T)$ is the
map corresponding to $T$.

Remark. According to a theorem of Chebyshev, this integral is not an elementary function when $\beta$ is irrational. Therefore I suppose that the solution of
your problem is also not an elementary function.

Here are some more detail. Let $T=1$. Let $F(z)$ be the integral I wrote above. Then $C$
is determined from the boundary correspondence: $C=1/F(1)$. Now 
$$G(z)=(-\cos(\pi z)+1)/2$$
maps the rectangular half-strip onto the upper half-plane, $(0,1,\infty)\mapsto (0,1,\infty)$. Therefore 
$$H(z)=F(G(z))/F(1)$$
maps the upper half of the rectilinear strip on the upper half of the slanted strip (both with $T=1$). So the solution of the Dirichlet problem (with $T=1$) is 
$$\Re(H^{-1}(z)).$$
Not very explicit, of course, since one has to invert the integral $F$. But OK for numerical computation.

Remark 2. The integral 
$$B_x(\beta,1-\beta):=\int_0^x\zeta^{\beta-1}(1-\zeta)^{-\beta}d\zeta$$
is called the incomplete Beta-function, and there is even the standard notation
$$I_x(\beta,1-\beta):=\frac{B_x(\beta,-\beta)}{B(\beta,1-\beta)}=F(x)/F(1).$$
To obtain simple estimates, expand it to the power series:
$$B_x(\beta,1-\beta)=\beta^{-1}x^\beta+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\beta(\beta+1)\ldots(\beta+n-1)}{n!(n+\beta)}x^{n+\beta}.$$
This is sufficient to determine your function on $(0,c)$ with any desired accuracy, unless $c$ is close to $1$. Near $1$ use a similar expansion
into powers of $x-1$.

For example, near $0$, $G(x)\sim x^2/4,$ so $$H(x)\sim\frac{1}{\beta 4^{\beta}B(\beta,1-\beta)}x^{2\beta},$$
$H^{-1}(x)\sim Cx^{1/(2\beta)}.$ Also notice that the series for $B_x$ has
positive coefficients which simplifies the estimates.

To obtain a lower estimate, you need the upper estimate to $B_x(\beta,1-\beta)$. We can write it as
$$B(x):=B_x(\beta,1-\beta)=\beta^{-1}x^\beta+f(x),$$
where $f$ is increasing (because it is a power series with positive coefficients), and we also know that $B(1)=B(\beta,1-\beta),$ therefore
$f(x)<f(1)=B(\beta,1-\beta)-1/\beta$. This will give an explicit constant $C$
in the lower estimate $Cx^{(1/2\beta)}$.

Comment: Should I map straight strip -> upper half plane -> upper half of the broken strip? I thought that I can go directly.

Comment: You should map upper half of  the straight strip onto the upper half-plane (by an elementary function), and then the upper half-plane to the broken strip (by that integral). The boundary correspondence should be $0\to 0,\; T\to T,\;\infty\to\infty$. By reflection this map extends to a map between the whole strips.

Comment: Thank you. I will try again.

Comment: If $F$ maps the straight strip onto the broken strip then the solution of Dirichlet problem is $\Re F^{-1}(z)/T$, the inverse function!

Comment: I think something missed in the function $G$.

Comment: @Do Iii: function $G$ seems fine: it is the conformal map of the upper half-strip onto the upper half-plane with $(0,1,\infty)\mapsto (0,1,\infty)$.

Comment: you wrote $(0,\pi,\infty)\mapsto (-1,1,\infty)$

Comment: This was a misprint. I corrected.

Comment: Hi @Alexandre do you know Giraud's maximum principle?

Comment: Not by name. What is this?

Comment: It's maximum principle for elliptic equation. It's in Isakov book "Inverse problems for partial differential equations" (2017), pp 107. He used it to find lower bound of harmonic functions. See pp 57.

Comment: I do not have the book. Probably I know this principle for harmonic functions but did not know that it is "Giraud".

Comment: If you state exactly what sort of estimate you need, I may think how to obtain it.

Comment: Okey. In fact, I want to get an estimate such $f(t)\ge Ct$ or $C t^c$ in the interval $(0, 1)$ (for some constant $C, c>0$) , or something similar, where $f$ is the underlying harmonic function. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is $Ct^{\pi/\alpha}$, but $C$ has to be found numerically (or by expanding the integral into a power series.

Comment: this is exactly what I expected. How can I prove that?

Comment: In my previous remark it must be $Ct^{\pi/2\alpha}$: I was confused with your picture, what do you call alpha.

Comment: Thank you, but I think this gives only a local inequality (near $0$ and $1$) and not on the whole intervals $(0,1)$.

Comment: Various inequalities can be written on the whole $(0,1)$ using the power series expansion.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a probability formulation: For $z\in \mathbb{C}$ inside the strip let $B_t^{(z)}$ the brownian motion starting at $z$. Then we have
$$ f(z)=\mathbb{P}\big(B_t^{(z)}\text{ touch the right half lines before the left half lines} \big)$$
This kind of formula is useful to get quantitative properties of $f$. For example
$$f(a+ib)=\frac{a}{T}-\frac{\cos(\alpha)}{\sin(\alpha)}\frac{|b|}{T} + \mathcal{O}(e^{-\gamma|b|})$$
for some $\gamma>0$ because the probability that $B^{(z)}_t$ cross the axis ($b=0$) before touching the right or the left lines decays exponentially.

RELATED QUESTION : I just want to react to the remark of Alexandre Eremenko because I didn't know the theorem of Chebyschev he mention.
Do you think that one can find an explicite formula for the eigenvetors and eigenvalues of the Laplacian $\Delta$ on a parallelogram (with Dirichlet b.c.) if its angular are rational?